# HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductId not found running 32bit app on 64bit Windows

Tags: registry, wow64

As title really. Looking in regedit the key-value exists, but the Wow6432 key (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion) doesn't have this key. This means a 32-bit app doesn't work on my 64-bit Windows version... which seems wrong, shouldn't the 32-bit app run without modifications? Or is this one case 32-bit apps have to be tweaked to work on 64bit Windows?

Comment: 32-bit applications should run perfectly fine on 64-bit OS. You said that the key-value exists. If it's not in Wow6432, where it is ?

Comment: @Adrian.. on 64-bit Windows, this value only exists in the 64-bit registry.

Answer (score 7):

Applications really shouldn't access this registry value directly. The best way to get this value is to use WMI to get the SerialNumber property of the [Win32_OperatingSystem class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28VS.85%29.aspx). This works fine from a 32-bit application running on Win64.

An alternative would be to use the [KEY_WOW64_64KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) flag when opening the registry key (does not work on Windows 2000.)

Comment: We're getting a bunch of registry values... in fact we don't necessarily know exactly what they are at coding time. It's just a few don't work. Is there a way I can pass flags to open the registry key, that will work on both 32 and 64-bit... don't really want to write different code for both if the Windows API can do this for me.

Comment: The KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag will work on both 32 and 64-bit. On 32-bit Windows it will just be ignored (except on Windows 2000 where it will probably crash), and on 64-bit Windows it will always read the values from the 64-bit registry.